# Decent command line parsing and execution for Java

Tags: java, symfony, console, console-application, command-line-arguments

I'm coming from Symfony2's world (PHP) and I'm trying to find a decent equivalent of its [Console](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html) component.

I tried a lot of stuff: args4j, jcommander, etc... But I want something like this : http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html#creating-a-basic-command. I want to be able to write a class where I configure my parameters (jcommander and args4j do that well), *AND* where I write my related `execute()` method, which would be called automatically. Does anything like that exist in Java?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So... After trying different so-called command-line arguments parsers, and seeing that no one were doing the job well enough (mainly no color handling), I decided to port Symfony2's Console component in Java. You can see the result here: [https://github.com/Nanocom/console](https://github.com/nanocom/console).

At the moment, it is still in beta-state. Still need to finish some parts, but you can already declare your commands and execute them.

Hope you'll like it! License is MIT.

And any contribution is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to Remember that symphony it's a framework for php projects, so could create projects, classes, etc from the command line because the framework was design for that, but with java it's different, java per se doesn't give you that functionality. In your case you need to find a framework that allows to create classes or projects and the most closest that I could recommend you it's the andromda cartridges combine with maven, but still you're gonna need to define your templates

Comment: Actually I think it would be really simple to provide this functionality in jcommander for example : I would create an interface with a single method execute() which would be implemented by your command classes, and jcommander would call itself the right command's execute() method.

Comment: And the Console component from Symfony is totally decoupled : it can be used alone. I just wonder if there isn't any similar component in Java.